# jqtouch javascript/ajax combo not working in android

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, jqtouch

In jqtouch, I'm calling several pages using ajax, in very vanilla fashion:

```
<li class="arrow"><a href="folder/another/somepage.html" >BRAVIA HDTVs</a><small class="counter">2</small></li></li>
```

I'm trying to use a video player (sublime player) on the remote pages.  In order to do that, I use the js provided by sublime: //script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.sublimevideo.net/js/something.js">

Then on my remote pages, to play the video I just put the code in a video class, which is defined by the js.

When I put this script in the head of my index page, things work great on iOS devices.  But the videos won't play in Android - the javascript isn't being called.  I can only play the video if I put it on the main index page, rather than the remote pages.

Any help?  Speak to me like the village idiot, please - thanks -

Answer (score 0):

Which version of jqTouch?  The Beta 2 (also known as version 109) linked to on their [home page](http://www.jqtouch.com/) is broken with Android, get the lastest version from [GitHub](https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch) for the best android support.  Note: look at the demo for how the formating of html changed between 109 and 161.

Answer (score 0):

jQtouch 1.0-b4-rc does not work with Android when using jQuery.  The internal links in your site won't work.  You have to use Zepto for it to work with Android.